# Prove that there exist differential functions $x=x(s,t)$,$y=y(s,t)$ defined around the point $(2,-1)$ which satisfy $xs^2+yt^2=1,x^2s+y^2t=xy-4$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Prove that there exist differential functions $x=x(s,t)$,$y=y(s,t)$ defined around the point $(2,-1)$ which satisfy $$xs^2+yt^2=1,x^2s+y^2t=xy-4$$ How many of these functions there are?

I've solved similar problems to this one where I had to prove in an equation of $x$ and $y$ I could write $y$ as a function of $x$. However I don't know how to solve this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can treat $s,t$ as coefficients and $x,y$ as variables. You have the system of equations

\begin{cases} s^2 x + t^2 y = 1 \\ sx^2 + ty^2 = xy - 4 \end{cases}

Solving for $y$ in the first equation and plugging it into the second gives
$$ sx^2 + t \left( \frac{1-s^2 x}{t^2} \right)^2 = x \left(\frac{1-s^2 x}{t^2}\right) - 4 $$

$$ st^3 x^2 + (1-s^2x)^2 = tx(1-s^2x) - 4t^3 $$
$$ (st^3 + s^4 + ts^2)x^2 - (2s^2+t)x + (1 + 4t^3) = 0 $$

This is a quadratic equation in $x$, whose solution exists if the determinant
$$ D(s,t) = (2s^2+t)^2 - 4(st^3 + s^4 + ts^2)(1+4t^3) \ge 0 $$

This is true since $D(2,-1) > 0$, so we're done.

You can also conclude that there are two possible solutions for $x$, and likewise for $y$

Comment: And how many of these functions will there be? As many as the roots of that quadratic equation? Also, even if $x$ is a function why can you treat it as if it was a real number? How do I interpret that two solutions of that system are $x=1$ and $x=\frac{-1}{3}$

Comment: The solutions are in terms of $s$ and $t$. You shouldn't be evaluating it at a single point. I'm not sure what you mean by "treating it as a real number", all I'm doing is rearranging terms to find an explicit expression for $x$ and $y$